# Reverse randomly chosen interval in a list

Tags: python, list, reverse

Consider the following example:

```
x = [ 8, 1 , 3 , 6 , 2 , 10 , 18, 4, 7 ]

n1 = randrange( len(x) )  
n2 = randrange( len(x) )  

while abs( n1 - n2 ) <= 2 :      # to make sure that they are at least two elements
    n1 = randrange( len(x) )
    n2 = randrange( len(x) )

---> n1 , n2 = 2 , 5
```

I want to revert the part `x[n1 + 1, n2] = [6,2]` between the two randomly chosen positions `n1`, `n2`.

The correct method should produce the following result (in the case that `n1=2`, `n2=5`)

```
 x = [ 8, 1 , 3 , **2** , **6** , 10 , 18, 4, 7 ]
```

I solved it myself but the result is quite 'ugly' and i am looking for a better method

```
x = [ 8, 1 , 3 , 6 , 2 , 10 , 18, 4, 7 ]

n1 = randrange( len(x) )
n2 = randrange( len(x) )

empty = []

while abs( n1 - n2 ) <= 2 :

    n1 = randrange( 10 )
    n2 = randrange( 10 )

    # sort n1, n2
    empty.append( n1 ) , empty.append( n2 )  
    empty = sort(empty)
    n1 , n2 = empty[0] , empty[1]

    # reverse the randomly chosen part
x_new = x[ n1 + 1 : n2 ]
x[ n1 + 1 : n2 ] = x_new[ :: -1 ]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about how to improve working code should be asked on [CodeReview.se] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from random import randint

x = [8, 1, 3, 6, 2, 10, 18, 4, 7]

n1 = randint(0, len(x)-4)
n2 = randint(n1 + 3, len(x)-1)

res = x[:n1+1] + x[n1+1:n2][::-1] + x[n2:]
```

which to me looks more elegant.

Example runs:

```
n1 = 3, n2 = 7, res:    [8, 1, 3, 6, 18, 10, 2, 4, 7]
n1 = 5, n2 = 8, res:    [8, 1, 3, 6, 2, 10, 4, 18, 7]
n1 = 2, n2 = 6, res:    [8, 1, 3, 10, 2, 6, 18, 4, 7]
n1 = 3, n2 = 8, res:    [8, 1, 3, 6, 4, 18, 10, 2, 7]
n1 = 1, n2 = 5, res:    [8, 1, 2, 6, 3, 10, 18, 4, 7]
n1 = 0, n2 = 5, res:    [8, 2, 6, 3, 1, 10, 18, 4, 7]
n1 = 3, n2 = 6, res:    [8, 1, 3, 6, 10, 2, 18, 4, 7]
n1 = 4, n2 = 8, res:    [8, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 18, 10, 7]
n1 = 0, n2 = 8, res:    [8, 4, 18, 10, 2, 6, 3, 1, 7]
```

The main thing here is to specify the ranges of the `randint` to avoid the `while` loops. Your requirements on the `n1` & `n2` are pretty straightforward. Advantages are that you do not have to worry about order or range length.

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import *
x = [ 8, 1 , 3 , 6 , 2 , 10 , 18, 4, 7 ]

n1 = randrange( len(x) )  
n2 = randrange( len(x) )  
n1,n2 = 2,5 ## remove this line after testing
n1, n2 = sorted([n1, n2])

if abs(n1-n2)>=2:
    tmp = x[:n1+1] + x[n2-1:n1:-1] + x[n2:]
    print(tmp)
```

Comment: to avoid the `if` statements you can also do `n1, n2 = sorted([n1, n2])` which orders them and reassigns them so that `n1 < n2`

Comment: note however that you are not making sure `n2 -  n1 > 2`